# How to create a nested json with key names in python?

Tags: python, json

I have the following data in a pandas dataframe.  I want to group the data based on month, then type.

```
month   hour    Type    count
0   4   0   Bike    8
1   4   0   Pedelec 16
2   4   1   Bike    9
3   4   1   Pedelec 4
4   4   2   Bike    18
... ... ... ... ...
412 12  21  Pedelec 15
413 12  22  Bike    7
414 12  22  Pedelec 10
415 12  23  Bike    2
416 12  23  Pedelec 15
```

I want to convert this to a nested json with field names. The code I use to create a dictionary  is this:

```
jsonfile=barchart.groupby(['month','Type'])[['hour','count']].apply(lambda x: x.to_dict('r')).reset_index(name='data').groupby('month')['Type','data'].apply(lambda x: x.set_index('Type')['data'].to_dict()).reset_index(name='data').groupby('month')['data'].apply(list).to_dict()
```

The output I get is in this format:

```
[{'month': 4,
  'values': [{'Bike': [{'hour': 0, 'count': 8},
     {'hour': 1, 'count': 9},
     {'hour': 2, 'count': 18},
     {'hour': 3, 'count': 2},
     {'hour': 4, 'count': 2},
 ...
     {'hour': 23, 'count': 14}],
    'Pedelec': [{'hour': 0, 'count': 16},
     {'hour': 1, 'count': 4},
     {'hour': 2, 'count': 12},
...
     {'hour': 23, 'count': 27}]}]},
```

Expected output:

```
[{'month': 4,
  'values': [{'Type': 'Bike': [{'hour': 0, 'count': 8},
     {'hour': 1, 'count': 9},
```

Comment: seems more like a question about data structure than JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following to create my deired format

```
jsonfile=barchart.groupby(['month','Type'])[['hour','count']].apply(lambda x: x.to_dict('r')).reset_index(name='data').groupby('month')['Type','data'].apply(lambda x: x.set_index('Type')['data'].to_dict()).reset_index(name='data').groupby('month')['data'].apply(list).to_dict()

json_arr=[]
for month,values in jsonfile.items():
    arr=[]
    for value in values:        
        for types, val in value.items():
            arr.append({"type": types, "values": val}) 
    json_arr.append({"month": month, "values": arr} )
```